# Jenkins crashes on npm install

Tags: jenkins, server, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to build our code through jenkins. I set it up 4 days ago and everything worked back then, but now every build fails. At first I thought it was because of the Jest testing I added (jest kept hanging instead of stopping) but I fixed that with --forceExit and the problem still exists.

With every build, it seems like Jenkins is crashing silently. I couldn't find any useful logs or anything. What is weird though, is that I tried to execute the commands through ssh in the jenkins folder where the project was placed by jenkins. When I did that, the npm install was really slow and the whole server was hanging. There are two other projects running from that server with nodejs, one with keystonejs that crashes every time this happens, the other one is plain express and had no problems. Any idea what can be the problem here?

EDIT: It's also happening more randomly and I couldn't connect to my server for a while through ssh or any other possibility.

Comment: Sounds like your server's running out of RAM. The NodeJS ecosystem's tooling has always had a reputation as being a real memory-eater.

Comment: Hmm... Is there anything I can do about it? I took a look and I'm using 64% of memory by default, but it's a DigitalOcean droplet with only 1GB ram and our organization doesn't have the money for more than that... :/ 2 other node projects are running without any problems though...

Comment: Reduce the number of packages you're using? Seriously, there's only really two options there - raise the RAM, or decrease the RAM requirement. And unless you're on the thinnest of shoestring budgets, I find it very surprising you can't raise the RAM cap on your droplet.

Comment: It's a platform for a non-profit organization that can't afford a much higher cost as we have no steady or high income.

Answer (score 0):

If is simple what you need to do, then don't use jenkins, is just to heavy.

Instead build an sh file that builds what you need, the down side of this is that you have to execute it by hand when you need to build.